# Optimal spacing between breaking points for a linearised function

Tags: optimization

This is my problem: I am looking for a way to optimally define the number of breaking points I need in order to approximate a quadratic function to a linear one. Right now, I have selected previously the number of breaking points ($m$) involved in the linearisation, but I'm dubious that this is causing me numerical stability issues in the whole problem. So in a general form I have

$y=x^{2}$

where

$x\in \mathbb{R} , \quad 0<x<x_{max}, \quad m\in \mathbb{Z}$

I am working with MILP and used separable programming to add non-linear constraints into the problem. The constraint is:

$x_{1}^{2} - x_{2}^{2} \ge K$

with the linearisation approach we have:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:sum_convex_separable2}
x_1=\sum_{i=0}^{r}m_{1i}\lambda_{1i} \quad  \text{and} \quad \phi_1(x_1)\approx \sum_{i=0}^{r}\phi_1(m_{1i})\lambda_{1i}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:sum_convex_separable3}
x_2=\sum_{i=0}^{r}m_{2i}\lambda_{2i} \quad  \text{and} \quad \phi_2(x_2)\approx \sum_{i=0}^{r}\phi_2(m_{2i})\lambda_{2i}
\end{equation}
The boundaries for $x_1$ and $x_2$ are:

$0\le x_1 \le x_{1_{max}}\qquad 0\le x_2 \le x_{2_{max}}\quad x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R} $

where lambdas need to meet the next adjacency conditions for both cases of $x_1$ and $x_2$:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:sum_convex_separable_constraints}
\lambda_0\le y_1, \quad \lambda_i \le y_i + y_{i+1} \quad \text{for} \quad i=1,\dots r-1, \quad \lambda_r \le y_r
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:sum_convex_separable_constraints2}
\sum_{i=0}^{r}\lambda_i=1, \quad \sum_{i=1}^{r}y_i=1,
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:sum_convex_separable_constraints3}
(\lambda,y)\ge 0, \quad y\in \{0,1\}
\end{equation}

At this moment, I selected the number of breaking points ($m$) arbitrarily and the space between kept constant, but I am not sure if this can be improved by changing the space between them.

What approach would be recommended here?

Thank you guys so much in advance,

Comment: Do you mean a piecewise linear approximation?  What do you mean by optimal?  You can always get a better approximation by making $m$ larger.

Comment: Yes! I mean that. I tried with a large number of $m$ but I also get warnings by the solver regarding the solution. I am using separable programming, where this $x^2$ variable is present in my problem, but I need to linearise it to add it to my MILP formulation. That's what I did but then I started wondering if there is a way to optimally select the spacing between those breaking points $m$, possibly improving my solution?

Comment: Can you provide the full MILP formulation?

Comment: What kind of variables are $x_1$ and $x_2$?  Do they have bounds?